# All my ANSWERS have disappeared from my Activity screen

Tags: support, status-completed

Happened just a few minutes ago...

[image]

Where did they go?

Comment: [Reported on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374104/).

Comment: This [has been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/374104/revisions).